# Extracting variable labels and using them as a string in SPSS macro

Tags: macros, spss

I am working on an SPSS macro that aims to create custom tables, each with a title that includes the variable label (as opposed to name, which it currently does). As a reduced example:

```
DEFINE !Ctables_loop (byvarlist = !CMDEND)
!DO !byvar !IN (!byvarlist)
CTABLES /titles Title= !QUOTE(!CONCAT('Table: ', !byvar)).
!DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.
```

Ideally, this solution would only involve the SPSS Macro language.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

possibly this should do it:

```
* run before running the macro.
SET  TVars=Labels OVars=Labels .
```

You can reach this also through EDIT => OPTIONS => OUTPUT.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, TVars and Ovars do not seem to affect variables specified by macros for titles.

Comment: you need to build your `CTABLES` syntax to use labels where you want them, and then have the macro use the same syntax for a number of variables. The macro has no direct effect on the results of the command - it just constructs syntax according to your definition and runs it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I resolved this issue myself (see the answer I posted) but if your solution is more effective, I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide an example of the solution. Thank you for  your efforts!

Comment: I see your solution - it's as I said - first you need to get to the correct `CTABLES` syntax (try also working through the menus till you get what you need, then paste to syntax), then you can reflect that in your macro to reproduce the table for many variables.

Answer (score 1):

As a partial solution:
By using '>TABLE' in the title section of the Ctables specification you can specify the variables used in the table using their labels. It is a bit inflexible as you are stuck with more than just the label (e.g. "var1 by var2" rather than having direct access to var1 label and var2 label), but I used a find-and-replace function to round off the formatting for the entire batch of tables after exporting.

I hope this helps other people with a similar problem.

The source and more information: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ko/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_ctables_titles_titles_captions_and_corner_text.htm